# Helm Charts create secrets in different namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have the following `secrets.yaml` in `templetes` in Helm Charts:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  USER_NAME: YWRtaW4=
  PASSWORD: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
```

I need to create the same secret in different namespace, for example, namespace `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, `test4`, how to specify the different namespace with the same `secrets` so the same `secret` can be created in different namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the namespace name in the `metadata` section like

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
  namespace: test1
type: Opaque
data:
  USER_NAME: YWRtaW4=
  PASSWORD: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
```

You can set a for loop with helm to create one `Secret` definition in each namespace.

Update.

```yaml
# values.yaml
namespaces:
  - test1
  - test2

# templates.secrets.tpl
{{- range .Values.namespaces }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
  namespace: {{ . | quote }}
type: Opaque
data:
  USER_NAME: YWRtaW4=
  PASSWORD: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm

{{- end }}


### output ###
---
# Source: base/templates/secrets.tpl

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
  namespace: "test1"
type: Opaque
data:
  USER_NAME: YWRtaW4=
  PASSWORD: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
  namespace: "test2"
type: Opaque
data:
  USER_NAME: YWRtaW4=
  PASSWORD: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
```

Comment: thanks! you mean add the range loop in the secrets.yaml or some other place?